# Find the last two digits of $157^{38}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$157 \equiv 57 \pmod {100}$

$38 = 2 \cdot 19$

so

$157^{38} \equiv 57^{38} \pmod {100} = (57^2)^{19} \equiv 49^{19} \pmod{100}$

This is where I get stuck.

Comment: $49^{19}=(49^2)^9 49$, if you want to continue your approach.

Comment: Actually, $49^2\equiv1\mod100$, so we can even do $49^{19}\equiv 49\cdot(49^2)^9\equiv 49\mod 100$

Answer (score 5):

With [Euler's Totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), we know that, for any $a$ coprime to $100$, that $$a^{\phi(100)}\equiv a^{40}\equiv1\mod 100$$
So that $157^{38}\equiv 57^{-2}\equiv 49^{-1}\mod 100$ so it comes down to finding the inverse of $49\mod 100$. With a little bit of searching, we see that this is $49$.

Comment: The answer actually appears to be 49. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=157%5E38+mod+100

Comment: Indeed, $49^2=2401\equiv 1 \pmod{100}$.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in my calculations. I edited the post. Thanks guys!

Comment: Use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find $49^{-1}\bmod 100$: note that $\gcd(49,100)=1$ and subtract consecutive equations:

$$100=(1)(100)+(0)(49)\\49=(0)(100)+(1)(49)\\2=(1)(100)+(-2)(49)\\1=(-24)(100)+(49)(49)$$

Therefore $(49)(49)\equiv 1\pmod{100}$, so $49^{-1}\equiv 49\pmod{100}$.

Comment: By which method do you conclude that $57^{-2}\equiv 49^{-1}\mod 100$?

Comment: @Unidan Because $57^2\equiv 49\pmod{100}$. Just notice that $57^2=3249$.